How do we know that the stationary states and corresponding eigenvalues of a quantum system forms a probability distribution?
In both lectures and my textbook (Introduction to Quantum Mechanics 3rd edition by Griffiths), I was told that a general solution to the time-dependent Schrodinger equation is a linear combination of stationary solutions:
$$ \Psi(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n \psi_n(x) e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}$$
where $\psi_n(x)$ are eigenstate solutions to the time-independent Schrodinger equation $\hat{H} \psi = E\psi$, and $E_n$ their respective eigenvalues.
What I struggle to believe is what is said next: "$|c_n|^2$ is the probability that a measurement of the energy would return the value $E_n$" (quoted directly from Griffiths). How do we know that we can interpret this as a probability distribution for energy and it's not just some set of numbers that happen to add to 1?
Having completed this quantum course, I understand that $\Psi$ exists in a Hilbert space and, in this case, is written in terms of basis "vectors" $\psi_ne^{-iE_nt/\hbar}$. $\Psi$ must be normalised over space which guarantees that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\Psi(x,t)|^2 dx =1 \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |c_n|^2=1$$
So clearly this $c_n$ "probability distribution" is normalised by construction, removing the possibility that the $|c_n|^2$ distribution just happens to be normalised as implied when introduced in Griffiths. 
To complicate things further, this example is then used to motivate the generalised statistical interpretation: that ALL observables with discrete spectra have this property!
Is this fundamental axiom of QM, or am I missing something important?

How do we know? Experiments! That’s the only way we know anything in physics. Theories are just constructed to match measurements.

But we couldn't have tested all possible states?? Its one thing to say that $|c_n|^2$ forms a probability distribution for states tested in the lab, to say its true for all states is another thing, let alone for all observables!

I understand experiments are the foundation of physics, but this is quite the assumption. And how would one even go about testing this? Forgive my naiveness about the lab, but it just seems unfeesable.

Yes it is an axiom, called Born rule. You cannot know if it is "true". But you can check what it implies for experiments, which you then can test.

Of course we have not tested all possible states. That’s irrelevant. Science is about falsification. No experiment has ever falsified the Born rule, so we assume it always works. Maybe someday you’ll design an experiment where it doesn’t, but don’t count on becoming famous that way.

Is this fundamental axiom of QM? QM has several postulates. Any good textbook covers them. If yours doesn’t, you can probably find questions on this site about them.

Or see Wikipedia.

The Born rule applies to all observable quantities, not just energy, and to all states, not just superpositions of discrete ones.

Hmm my brain is saying you're right, but I still have this nagging feeling from my intuition about this. Maybe if I had learned this in a different way it wouldn't be such a problem, or my standard for theoretical proof is just too high!

Either way, I'll take it as a questionable postulate and continue with my studies. Thank you for your help!

If you accept what is called the "statistical or ensemble interpretation," see, e.g., here, then the meaning of $|c_n|^2= |\left< \psi_n|\Psi \right>|^2$ as the probability of finding the system in the state $\psi_n$ is a lot more natural axiom, at least to me. But note I am not saying that you should accept the statistical interpretation rather than the "Copenhagen" or the "Everett", it is just an easier "thing" to swallow to me, but at the same time it is also the least popular interpretation of the three and for good reasons.

You say your standard for theoretical proof is too high. This is not a theoretical result. It is an experimental result the requires experimental proof, not theoretical. Take any experiment in quantum mechanics that relies on measuring some observable. The results are all consistent with the Born rule. That's the proof. Like any experimental result: If all experiments agree with the predictions of a theory, then we assume the theory is right.

All postulates are questionable---that is the point of their existence. A physics theory explains phenomena by making assumptions that we call postulates, and those are the parts that are to be scrutinised as being potentially wrong. We try to assume as few postulates and as simple postulates as possible, predict as much as possible, and then check if those predictions are wrong. As of now, this Born's rule postulate is extremely well-tested. But yes, there are better ways to see physics, in which this rule is intuitive, but alas, it is not the standard way to teach quantum theory.


How do we know that we can interpret this as a probability distribution for energy and it's not just some set of numbers that happen to add to 1?

We don't know, but we assume, and nobody has managed to prove that it is wrong. There is no full satisfactory explanation of why it is correct either, perhaps because the measurement problem is not solved.
But we can alter the question: why do we assume that rule?
In some cases of measurement (e.g. spin measurements) it is the best way to use the psi function to predict frequencies, that we know.
When Schroedinger wrote his equation for $\psi$, he and other people thought it is somehow connected with electron(s), but it was not clear how. Maybe electrons are really charged waves, so $\psi$ is really one-to-one or close description of what exists; or maybe they are really point particles, and $\psi$ gives probability of their position or momentum.
The first interpretation did not catch on, because in various experiments, electrons appear on screens or detectors as small dots, one can even record trajectories of single electrons. So people realized the psi function is not literally the electron; it seems to be more like some new mathematical object, related to frequency of certain observations/measurements, e.g. density of points on a film in scattering experiments.
Max Born proposed to interpret $\psi$ that one can get out of scattering calculations based on the Schroedinger equation, as follows: when there is a constant source of electrons/alpha particles, producing them with some definite momentum, and they scatter on target to all directions, then $|\psi(\theta,\phi)|^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$ is a number proportional to frequency of scattering detection events where the particle is detected (far from the scattering center) with angles somewhere between $(\theta;\theta+d\theta),(\phi,\phi+d\phi)$.
This turned out to agree with observations, e.g. the Rutherford scattering (and other more complicated scatterings). Calculations of $\psi$, together with the Born rule, predict well the observed frequencies of the actual scattering events in experiments.
So at least when $\psi$ is a function of particle coordinates (above, angles), $|\psi|^2$ for the correct $\psi$ can be understood as a probability density. Generalizing a little, we can postulate that for properly normalized $\psi$, value $|\psi(x)|^2$, where $x$ stands for all coordinates of the system in configuration space, is probability per unit volume of configuration space. The actual probability that the system is observed to be in any given small region of configuration space $\tau$, is the integral
$$
P(\tau) = \int_{\tau}|\psi(x)|^2 d\tau,
$$
where integration goes over the region $\tau$.
Similarly for momentum, a related continuous quantity, probability density is $|\tilde{\psi}(p)|^2$, where $\tilde{\psi}$ can be calculated from $\psi(x)$.
This leads to the idea of statistical interpretation, where the electron always appears as a dot on measurement, but many electrons in the same macroscopic experimental situation have "random positions and momenta" with probability given by $\psi$, so we have "probability clouds". This seems confirmed by various scattering and imaging experiments showing that the image of many electrons in the same situation (e.g. electron near nucleus in a crystal) is a pattern of many clouds of atomic size (e.g. X-ray diffraction on crystals and reconstructing the electron density).
However, not all physics quantities are like position and momentum (continuous variables). Sometimes we want to talk about other quantities, which in classical physics were functions of positions and momenta, such as angular momentum or energy, and turn out to have discrete values in quantum theory. However, for probabilities of such discrete values, the above formula (with integration) is inapplicable, because there is no obvious way to make it depend on the discrete value. There is no way to get a discrete-value-specific region $\tau$ to integrate over.
Instead, there is the second Born rule: the probability that a measurement of discretely counted quantity $Q$ gives value $Q_n$, is
$$
P_n = \bigg|\int_{whole~config~space} \Phi_n^*\psi ~d\tau\bigg|^2,
$$
where integration goes over the whole configuration space (not over some small region selected), and where $\Phi_n$ is the eigenfunction associated with the discrete value $Q_n$:
$$
\hat{Q}\Phi_n = Q_n\Phi_n.
$$
Notice this second rule is very different: 1) the integration region is not affected by the specific result selected as it was in the first Born rule, but the integrand is; and 2) we are squaring only after the integration, not before, as in the first Born rule.
This second Born rule looks strange at first, but mathematically it is the simplest way to derive probability for a discrete result from $\psi$. It is hard to check/motivate directly from experiments  in the way the first Born rule is, because we actually never observe these discrete variables directly, we always infer them from other things, either mathematical convenience/consistency, or from measurements of position.
For example, spin projection is discrete, but we can't measure it directly; instead, we measure position of atom after it has passed magnetic field, and from that measured position, we infer which discrete value the spin projection had. It turns out from the Stern-Gerlach experiment and its variations with SG magnets in different orientations, that observed frequencies of spin projection results obey the second Born rule (or so we believe, I haven't done the experiment). For discrete variables, no better or simpler scheme than the second Born rule has been found.
For other discrete quantities, such as energy of an atom/molecule, I don't know how to connect them to position measurement and verify the same rule works; we really assume it works for all discrete quantities just as for the spin. However, if you don't like this assumption, it often does not matter, especially when we're not interested in energy or angular momentum of a single atom, and there is no measurement of those. If we're after some macroscopic effect of many atoms/molecules, such as intensity of absorption/emission of radiation, we can get those directly from $\psi$, without the need to assume the discrete variables like energy actually realize in the sample with some frequency, and without the need to talk about and calculate that frequency. Already Schroedinger has shown how to calculate absorption and emission spectra without any need to consider probabilities of discrete variables (or discrete quantum states or jumps, confusing people since the old quantum theory), or the need to use the second Born rule. One can just calculate $\psi$ in a given system and then calculate its effect on EM radiation, using Maxwell's equations.

There are a couple of positions on why the square amplitudes are probabilities: the Born rule. The most common position is that this is an axiom of quantum physics.
Another position is that the Born rule can be explained in quantum physics without collapse. One explanation is that the only rule compatible with decision theoretic probability is the Born rule:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906015
https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2718
Another approach involves envariance: looking at symmetry properties of quantum states that are robust under interaction with the environment
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405161
